# sem post after sem wait doesn't work

Tags: c, semaphore

I'm trying to create a pipe based shared memory.
I'm also using semaphores, and I have a problem with one of my semaphores (maybe I do have more problems, but I didn't notice yet)

This semaphore initialization:

```
if (sem_init(&(sem_readers), 1, 0) < 0) {
    perror("Error sem_init");
    return -1;
}
```

The usage:

First the father (the reading end):

```
if (sem_wait(&(sem_readers)) < 0) {
    perror("ERROR: sem_wait i");
    return -1;
}
```

Then the son, the writing end:

```
if (sem_post(&(sem_readers)) < 0) {
    perror("ERROR: sem_post SEM_SHM_PIPE_PIPE");
    return -1;
}
```

For some reason, the father stucks on this wait() of the semaphore, even though the son do the post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have unnamed semaphores in multiple processes, as they are stored only in memory and the memory for two processes are *not* shared.

You have to use [`sem_open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sem_open.html) to create a named semaphore before the `fork`, and then in the child process also use `sem_open` again to open the existing semaphore.

Comment: How can it be? So what use do I have to the unnamed semaphore ?

Comment: @hudac Unnamed (memory-based) semaphores can be used in a threaded program, as it's still a single process with a single memory-map.

Comment: But unnamed semaphores can be shared with other process, using the 2nd init argument: pshared. From the manual: If pshared is nonzero, then the semaphore is shared between processes, and should be located in a region of shared memory. That means that if he uses a shared memory he can access the semaphore.

Comment: @Cookie503 Of course, but it creates extra steps, especially if the OP doesn't use shared memory already too.

Comment: This is not necessarily true. You *can* have unnamed semaphores in multiple processes, but you have to set up shared memory between the processes first. This is accomplished with http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html

Answer (score 1):

The way you wrote your program the parent process and the child process work with two different semaphores. You can use a named semaphore as Joachim Pileborg pointed out, but you can also use unnamed semaphores between a process and its child, just store the semaphore in shared memory:

```
  /* place semaphore in shared memory */
  sem_t *mutex = mmap(NULL,sizeof(sem_t),
        PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
  if (!mutex) {
    perror("Out of memory");
  }

  /* create, initialize semaphore */
  if (sem_init(mutex, 1, 1) < 0) {
    perror("semaphore initilization");
    exit(0);
  }
  int ret = fork();

  //use your semaphore...

  if (sem_destroy(sema) < 0) {
    perror("sem_destroy failed: %s", strerror(errno));
    exit(0);
  }
  /* don't forget to unmap the memory */
  if (munmap(sema, sizeof(sem_t)) < 0) {
    perror("munmap failed: %s", strerror(errno));
    exit(0);
  }
```